# How to understand auc_precision_recall curve in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard, precision-recall, auc

#### Versions:

`TensorFlow: 1.6.0`
`TensorBoard: 1.6.0`

#### What i'm doing and familiar with:

1. Using Pre-made `Estimator` [tf.estimator.DNNClassifier](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.6/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/DNNClassifier) to train a binary classification model with a `largely skewed dataset`(namely imbalanced dataset).
2. So, i have to use `Precision-Recall` curve to chooses an optimal model instead of `AUC` curve.
3. I changed nothing to the `tf.estimator.DNNClassifier`(Of course, i did changed these three parameters:`hidden_units`, `feature_columns`, `model_dir`).
4. After the accuracy of the model reached a threshold and stop to optimize, i have to continue training like this: pick out one feature iteratively from all features and do training, so that i can getting rid of some noise features as possible.
5. I did as `Step 4`, every time i picked out a feature i got a new training result and a new pictures about `auc_precision_recall` curve from TensorBoard.
   Namely, When i picked out `FEATURE_A` i got `figure A`, picked out `FEATURE_B` i got `figure B`,and picked out `FEATURE_C` i got `figure C`.
   Pictures as follow:
   [figure A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6QMN.jpg),    [figure B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfTaT.jpg),    [figure C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVpU7.jpg)
6. Descriptions about the above `auc_precision_recall` curve figures:

   - `x` axes: indicate training step.
   - `y` axes: range from 0 to 1 (this is what i want to know: what does `y` mean?).
7. Following is a standard `Precision-Recall` curve from this [site](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~jdavis/davisgoadrichcamera2.pdf).(I paste it here just for us to discuss my problem easily).
   [standard Precision-Recall curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIErZ.jpg)
8. Descriptions about the above standard `Precision-Recall` curve:

   - `x` axes: Recall, range from 0 to 1.
   - `y` axes: Precision, range from 0 to 1.

#### My Problems:

1. What's the meaning for a value in `y` axes in a TensorBoard `auc_precision_recall` curve?
2. What's the relationship between a TensorBoard `auc_precision_recall` curve and a standard `Precision-Recall`  curve?
3. Why the value in `y` axes in a TensorBoard `auc_precision_recall` curve so strange?

   - In `figure A`, the first point is `(x, y) = (1, 0.5009)`, why `y` is `0.5009` even in the `1st Step`? and also why most of the other values also keeps in 0.5(from `figure A` we can easily read about this)?
   - Also in `figure B`, the first point is `(x, y) = (7, 0.4625)`, why this `y`(0.4625) value is not equal to a value near 0 even in the first a few training steps as `figure C` shows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer: this is a bug in the tensorflow version 1.6.0 caused by the wrong way(**trapezoidal**) to calculate the value of `AUC_PR`, and this bug has fixed in the latest version 1.8.0 by [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/1f5324ca69bc1017972eef8e418691cff9a86dd7). So if you are training a largely skewed dataset, remember to update tensorflow to the latest version 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

To answer questions 1 and 2. AUC means Area Under the Curve. Therefore, you are looking at Area under the Precision-Recall (PR) Curve. The y-axis gives you this area, which is between 0 and 1 because these are min and max areas achievable on a PR curve.